# How do i use my calculated fields in controls using parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

So basically i have created different calculated fields like YTD,MTD,QTD etc and i can use them on the my table using filters but what i want now is to use a parametere to add control like a dropdown or a list and choose one of these calculated fields so it implies on the table on its own. I am struggling to write the logic as i am new to quicksight can anyone help

I have created a parameter so far a string type and started for just one function by writing the logic as
"ifelse(${SORT}='YTD',YTD,0)". It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you have created these calculated fields in the Analysis in Quicksight? If so then you cannot use them as Controls / Parameters. You must create the calculated fields in the data preparation phase. This can be done (with permissions) in Quicksight by editing the dataset. See (same) answer with a few more details at: https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/passing-value-from-calculated-field-to-a-parameter/1353

Comment: Actually what needs to be done is to make a single calculated field for all these calculations and then make a control with a list and you can apply the filter on the new field on your visual and filter out only the true values and it will work